# Need a regex that can remove a number and following dot

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have some strings that come in from lists like this:

1. Ugly Christmas Sweater
2. Hoverboard
3. Corona Beer Warmer
   ...
4. Nuclear Powered Heat Socks

For example "2. Hoverboard" would then be "Hoverboard" after applying a magical regex to it.

Numbers are ok in the string. I would like to strip an numbers that are followed by ".". For example

21 Jump Street

is totally fine.

Comment: `sub(/\d+\.\s*/, '')`

Comment: @Avinash's regex returns strings that are fine, if not totally fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `/^\s*\d+\.\s/`:

```
"1. This is a string".sub(/^\s*\d+\.\s/, '') #=> "This is a string"
"1 Is a string".sub(/^\s*\d+\.\s/, '') #=> "1 Is a string"
"1. 3.5".sub(/^\s*\d+\.\s/, '') #=> "3.5"
"Number: 3.5".sub(/^\s*\d+\.\s/, '') #=> "Number: 3.5"
```

What it does:

- `^`: Start of the string
- `\s*`: Whitespace (`\s`), 0 or more (`*`)
- `\d+`: Any digit (`\d`), 1 or more (`+`)
- `\.`: `.` character
- `\s`: Any whitespace

Comment: The reason I chose this answer is because of the extra ^

Comment: botbot, you didn't say the digits necessarily start at the beginning of the strings. Among other things, they could be indented, as your example may suggest.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Added a catch for whitespace at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

This is continued from @Avinash Raj's comment in the question section.
Slightly modified and to explain things a bit.

```
str = '2. Hoverboard'
str.sub(/\s*\d+\.\s*/, '')
# => "Hoverboard"
```

`\s*` means, zero or more white space characters, `\d+` means, followed by 1 or more digits, followed by a `.`, and then `\s*` again means followed by zero or more white space characters.

Then, we are using [String#sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub) method to replace the first occurrence of the regex pattern with the second argument.

Comment: You could save characters by referencing @Avinash's comment. Hmmm. Maybe not.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It's slightly modified and I tried to explain things a bit. If you think it should not be an answer, please let me know. I will happily delete it :)

Comment: I have no problem with your answer, as it now reads. I just  think it's a courtesy to reference an earlier comment when it forms the basis for an answer.